# Python module not working when using other account

Tags: django, python-2.7, centos6

I have created a new user from in CentOS named nafd_it.

Then given ownership to the virtualenv nafd folder. The folder contains the django application and python2.7.

```
sudo chown -R nafd_it /env/nafd
sudo chmod -R g+w /env/nafd
```

In my root virtual environment when I launch my python2.7, I can importing time module.
But when I change user

```
su - nafd_it

-bash-4.1$ source bin/activate
(nafd)-bash-4.1$ python
```

Inside the python environment when I issue an `import time`

I'm getting

```
ImportError: No module named time
```

I already change the folder permission for `/env/nafd` folder to `chmod -R ugo+rwx env/nafd`

How can I make the user nafd_it read the python module?

Answer (score 0):

Before I forgot to solve this problem again, I manage to pass this firewall by adding the user `nafd_it` to root group.

`usermod -a -G root 'nafd_it'`

I can now access the module properly using the nafd_it user.